# Having problems adding icon in Xcode

Tags: xcode

How do I add an app icon on xcode? I tried using an image from google saved it onto my desktop and carry dropped it on the app icon, however this didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the .png file to your Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

Comment: thanks! i was using a jpg file which wouldn't work, once i made the switch it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

The icon is obviously used for the home screen, and the launch image is displayed when the app loads. Because you need to provide support for both Retina Display (4 and higher) and standard (3GS and lower), the files should be according the following specifications:

- Standard icon 57 × 57, named Icon.png
- Retina Display icon 114 × 114, named Icon@2x.png
- Standard launch image 320 × 480, named Default.png
- Retina Display launch image 640 × 960, named Default@2x.png

After you have these created according these standard size and naming conventions, replace the canned files that PhoneGap already added by overwriting them in your project folder.

Answer (score 6):

Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

Answer (score 1):

You need to observe the file format, jpg's are mostly used.
Also you need to observe the correct dimensions of the image, if you hover over the icon's placeholder, you see for e.g. iPhone/iPod non-retina 57x57 pixels. In a graphic editor you can change the canvas size.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [asset catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1), this will help organize all your images and icons.